# What should I do to increase security on my server

Tags: vps, web-hosting, security

I have recently purchase VPS2 package from knownhost. I created support ticket with authentic information of the account too for setting up the server and fixing some issues. I have been long with it, its just few days. In those few days i got 3 emails notifying that someone is trying to access my account, but i don't know why and who? I just got some notifications like:

```
Time:     Wed Apr 13 08:12:27 2011 +0000
IP:       74.63.223.72 (US/United States/72-223-63-74.servebyte.net)
Failures: 10 (pop3d)
Interval: 300 seconds
Blocked:  Permanent Block

Log entries:

Apr 13 08:10:57 host dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<root>, method=PLAIN, rip=74.63.223.72, lip=204.197.252.160
Apr 13 08:11:43 host dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<admin>, method=PLAIN, rip=74.63.223.72, lip=204.197.252.160
Apr 13 08:12:17 host dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<webmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=74.63.223.72, lip=204.197.252.160
Apr 13 08:12:17 host dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<admin>, method=PLAIN, rip=74.63.223.72, lip=204.197.252.160
Apr 13 08:12:19 host dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<admin>, method=PLAIN, rip=74.63.223.72, lip=204.197.252.160
Apr 13 08:12:19 host dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<webmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=74.63.223.72, lip=204.197.252.160
Apr 13 08:12:21 host dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<admin>, method=PLAIN, rip=74.63.223.72, lip=204.197.252.160
Apr 13 08:12:21 host dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<webmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=74.63.223.72, lip=204.197.252.160
Apr 13 08:12:23 host dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<webmaster>, method=PLAIN, rip=74.63.223.72, lip=204.197.252.160
Apr 13 08:12:23 host dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<admin>, method=PLAIN, rip=74.63.223.72, lip=204.197.252.160
```

So what may be objective of such activities to access my account and how can i improve security on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entries in the above message are simply failed POP3 logins. It's likely that the IP you currently have was previously in use by another customer of knownhost who was running a POP3 server. There's not much of a threat here as long as your email accounts have nice strong passwords. If you do think these attempts are malicious, you can certainly block the source IP addresses with IPtables, or implement an automatic blocking service like fail2ban.

Answer (score 0):

What about providing SSL only Services for POP/IMAP? To lock out these kids with their bruteforce scripts you could use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which would ban these ips after a configurable amount of unsuccessful connection attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running john the ripper on your machine for a few days.  It will report to you if any passwords are easy to guess.  This will help you ensure your passwords and not easily guessed by brute-force methods.

http://www.openwall.com/john/